# Yii2 SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: activerecord, yii2

In my ModelSearch I have the code like this:

```
$candidates = Candidate::find();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
   'query' => $candidates
]);
```

and then I'm trying to proceed this query:

```
$candidates->andFilterWhere([
   ' or ',
   ['like', 'candidate.something', $this->word],
   ['like', 'candidate.anything', $this->word]
]);
```

and at the end i return `$dataProvider`.

I remember that i used that kind of piece of code many times and never had any problems with it, but unexpectedly after the whole trying I still receive the same error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `candidate` WHERE Array OR 'like' GROUP BY `candidate`.`id`) `c`
```

When I write the piece of code in that way:

```
$candidates->andFilterWhere([
   ' or ',
   'candidate.`something` LIKE "%' . $this->word . '%" ',
   'candidate.`anything` LIKE "%' . $this->word . '%"',
]);
```

It seems to work, but i don't want to do it like that. I suppose that the clue of the problem can be somewhere else, but I have no idea where else i should look for it.

Any sugestions?

Best regards.

**[EDIT] SOLVED:**

[@arogachev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4323648/arogachev)'s prompt turned out to be right way: **just delete spaces from** "`or`" **made it work.**
QueryInterface doesn't recognize condition operator which is not trimmed, thats the reason it got fooled (and me by the way).

Comment: Please show query constructing process fully. Also try to strip spaces in `or`, see examples [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).

Comment: @arogachev , you are right. The problem was with those spaces surrounding `or` operator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT] SOLVED:**

@arogachev's prompt turned out to be right way: just delete spaces from " `or` " made it work. QueryInterface doesn't recognize condition operator which is not trimmed, thats the reason it got fooled (and me by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Try using  or like

```
$candidates->andFilterWhere([
  ['or like', 'candidate.something', $this->word],
  ['or like', 'candidate.anything', $this->word]
]);
```